# Elasticsearch filtering by specific token

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm new to elasticsearch and I'm trying to use it for my web development college project.
Is it possible to aggregate the data below by a specific subset of the IP address?

```
{
    {
        "ip": "192.168.0.1",
        "host": "Gateway"
    },
    {
        "ip": "192.168.2.3",
        "host": "A"
    },
    {
        "ip": "192.168.2.4",
        "host": "B"
    }
}
```

I want to be able to aggregate totals based ip address subset of xxx.xxx.2.*
so the total value should return 2, (host: A and B)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Wildcard Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) if you want to get total value only. Like:

```
post ipaddress\data\_search
{
    "query":{
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "wildcard" : { "ip" : "*.*.2.*" }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: can all numbers be aggregated in the 3rd address block? for instance if there were 3's and 2's in that block I can aggregate totals based values?